# MYSQL json query where array is present in json field likes

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, json-query

I wonder if this query is possible using json query.

I need to select all records that have more than 3 values a like.
for example, I have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Database record has:

```
# ["1","2","3","9","4","2"]     selected <--- this contains 1,2,3
# ["4","5","6","10","11","12"]  selected <--- this contains 4,5,6
# ["1","2","3","4","20","21"]   selected <--- this contains 1,2,3,4
4. ["1","2","21","22","23","24"]   not selected <-- only contains 1,2`
```

I was trying this query

```
select * from `combinations` where json_contains(`combination`, '"0"') and json_contains(`combination`, '"1"') and json_contains(`combination`, '"3"')
```

Comment: You are looking if value are lower than 7? Also, what is the issue with your query?

Comment: im looking for records that contain any of this array [1,2,3,4,5,6] but i need 3 or more must be present. for example, 5,3,1 should be in the field or 2,1,6.

Comment: I made [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053011/10952503). Check it then don't forget to accept it with the check mark on the top left of it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you did, you should use json method from mysql. You need to use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) (require mysql 8.0+).

By doing (here with last line of your example)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    JSON_TABLE('["1","2","21","22","23","24"]', "$[*]" COLUMNS(myId INT PATH "$")) a
```

You will have this table:

| myId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 21 |
| 22 |
| 23 |
| 24 |

After getting this, you should count for values with `COUNT(*)` and a `WHERE` clause that filter. I'm using the `IN` case as you have a small amount of possible value, but feel free to use `<` for example.

Final query with everything:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*)
        FROM JSON_TABLE(t.json, "$[*]" COLUMNS(myId INT PATH "$")) a
        WHERE myId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    ) as amount, json
FROM
    test t
```

Result:

| amount | json |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | ["1","2","3","9","4","2"] |
| 3 | ["4","5","6","10","11","12"] |
| 4 | ["1","2","3","4","20","21"] |
| 2 | ["1","2","21","22","23","24"] |

You can find example at [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bG52it7X3VmGUHSDegYWjr/0).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by splitting the array into rows using `json_table` then check if arrays contains more than 2 elements from `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` :

I used `distinct` to count elements only ones, you can remove it if you want to count duplicates

```
with cte as (
  select distinct t.myjson, j.combination
  from combinations t
  join json_table(
    t.myjson,
    '$[*]' columns (combination varchar(50) path '$')
  ) j
)
select myjson, count(*)
from cte
where combination in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
group by myjson
having count(*) > 2
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wr7pUnK4vbHUnC1741o8H/1)